# Using in Cygwin: some dll and jar files that are built for windows

Tags: java, terminal, java-native-interface, cygwin

I have the following files on a windows machine:

```
'Example.java'
'File.jar'
'Library.dll'
```

I successfully compile and run the `Example.java` using the following lines in windows command prompt:

```
 javac  -cp  " . ; C:Path_to_Folder\File.jar "    Example.java
 java   -cp  " . ; C:Path_to_Folder\File.jar "    Example
```

However, I am not comfortable with windows command prompt and rather would like to use Cygwin. Is that possible to run the above commands in Cygwin terminal? Should I use the `javac/java` that come with windows or the ones that come with Cygwin?

Comment: Cygwin has no Java, so you need to use the windows one.

Comment: @matzeri Ok, so java is there in Cygwin and no need for new installation. But can I run the above two commands from Cygwin terminal? After replacing those backslash with slash.

Comment: try with just `javac  -cp  ' . ; C:Path_to_Folder\File.jar '` but you need to put the in the PATH the location of the java machine,

Comment: @matzeri  I could successfully compile my `Example.java` file using `javac`. How about running `Example` using `java`? Does `java` load `.dll` file from Cygwin?